# Chaining perf with FlameGraph

Tags: validation, sh

This is my first serious shell script, so it is probably horrible.

### Problem statement

I decided to improve my profiling skills as so far they were mostly about hand-rolling counters and timers. After trying out better profiling tools and techniques I noticed that previously I was just rolling my face over keyboard until the metrics got better. Yet to do profiling in a consistent and hassle-free way is a bit tedious.

`perf` is a profiling utility used to collect software and hardware metrics about program's execution or entirety of the machine. It outputs binary files that can be fed into variety of tools, but I decided on [FlameGraph](https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph). The problem with it is that it takes several commands and the overall process is rather boring. I decided to automate it with a shell script that invokes needed commands with the flags I usually use.

## Code

```
#!/bin/sh

usage="$(basename "$0") [-g fgdir] [-h] -t target

where:
    -h  show this help text
    -t  executable to run under perf
    -g  root directory of FlameGraph repository https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph
"

fgroot="."
while getopts 'g:ht:' option; do
    case "$option" in
      h) echo "$usage"
         exit
         ;;
      t) if ! [ -x "$(command -v "$OPTARG")" ]; then
            echo "$OPTARG is not executable"
            exit 1
         fi
         echo "$OPTARG"
         target="$OPTARG"
         ;;
      g) fgroot="$OPTARG"
         echo "$OPTARG"
         ;;
      :) printf "missing argument for -%s\n" "$OPTARG" >&2
         echo "$usage" >&2
         exit 1
         ;;
     \?) printf "illegal option: -%s\n" "$OPTARG" >&2
         echo "$usage" >&2
         exit 1
         ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))

scpath="$fgroot/stackcollapse-perf.pl"
fgpath="$fgroot/flamegraph.pl"
echo "$scpath" "$fgpath"
if ! [ "$(command -v "$scpath")" ]; then
  printf "could not find stackcollapse-perf.pl\n"
  exit 1
fi

if ! [ "$(command -v "$fgpath")" ]; then
  printf "could not find flamegraph.pl\n"
  exit 1
fi


#filename=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%Hh-%Mm-%Ss").perf
filename=$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z")
perf record -g --call-graph=dwarf -F 99 "$target"
perf script > "$filename".perf
$scpath "$filename".perf > "$filename".collapsed
$fgpath "$filename".collapsed > "$filename".svg
```

---

Is the interface idiomatic (command line argument letters, usage string, etc)? Is it possible to write the shell script in an easier to understand way? Is there any more useful checking I should do inside my code?

---

Sample output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your diagnostic messages are being sent to stdout; you want to send all of them to stderr (`>&2`). A good practice is to include the script's name in these messages, so you can see who is emitting a message when you have scripts calling scripts calling scripts etc.

(Many of these `echo`s were apparently just for debugging anyway; I commented out those instead.)

As a minor refactoring, I turned `usage` into a function.

I made `usage` return exit code 1, which is a fairly common convention, and thus changed the other error cases to return exit codes 2, 3, etc to allow a caller to distinguish between these cases.

Perhaps make up your mind regarding whether to use `echo` or `printf`. The former is less versatile but often more compact for simple messages.

The check for whether the argument to `-t` is executable or not is slightly problematic; `command -v` will not output anything if it isn't. But I don't see an easy way to rephrase that. Perhaps the error message should be rearticulated, though?

The conventional way to use `command -v` is to simply run it directly, without a command substitution; perhaps see also [Why is testing "$?" to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern) for a discussion, though that's not exactly the problem here.

```
#!/bin/sh

me="$(basename "$0")"

usage () {
    printf '%s\n' >&2 \
    "$me [-g fgdir] [-h] -t target" "" \
    "    where:" \
    "    -h  show this help text" \
    "    -t  executable to run under perf" \
    "    -g  root directory of FlameGraph repository https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph" ""
    exit 1
}


fgroot="."
while getopts 'g:ht:' option; do
    case "$option" in
      h) usage;;
      t) if ! [ -x "$(command -v "$OPTARG")" ]; then
            echo "$me: $OPTARG is not executable" >&2
            exit 2
         fi
         # echo "$OPTARG"
         target="$OPTARG"
         ;;
      g) fgroot="$OPTARG"
         # echo "$OPTARG"
         ;;
      :) printf "%s: missing argument for -%s\n" "$me" "$OPTARG" >&2
         usage
         ;;
     \?) printf "%s: illegal option: -%s\n" "$me" "$OPTARG" >&2
         usage
         ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))

scpath="$fgroot/stackcollapse-perf.pl"
fgpath="$fgroot/flamegraph.pl"
# echo "$scpath" "$fgpath"
if ! command -v "$scpath" >/dev/null; then
  printf "%s: could not find stackcollapse-perf.pl\n" "$me" >&2
  exit 3
fi

if ! command -v "$fgpath" >/dev/null; then
  printf "%s: could not find flamegraph.pl\n" "$me" >&2
  exit 4
fi

filename=$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z")
perf record -g --call-graph=dwarf -F 99 "$target"
perf script > "$filename".perf
$scpath "$filename".perf > "$filename".collapsed
$fgpath "$filename".collapsed > "$filename".svg
```

Options should arguably be optional; but I refrained from removing the `-t` option in case you need it to stay for reasons of backwards compatibility.

If `stackcollapse-perf.pl` accepts input from stdin, you could avoid creating the `.collapsed` file. These temporary files in the current directory which can get overwritten at any time are still a bit of a wart.